# Jquery Function After Class Change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say that I have a button with fuction add a class named `open` to a  `div#foo` element, and when it's all done I need to change other element style `div#bar`

fyi the default style of the `div#bar` is `position:fixed`

So here is my code

```
function checkForChanges()
{
    if ($('#foo').hasClass('open'))
        $('#bar').css('position','relative');
    else
        setTimeout(checkForChanges, 500);
}  
$(checkForChanges);
```

It woks like a charm, but the problem is how to revert the style of the `#bar` to the default if `#foo` no longer have class named `open`?

Frankly I have no experience in javascript so I have no idea about 'setTimeout(checkForChanges, 500);`

All I need is change the `#bar` style when `#foo` has class `open` and get the `#bar` style back to the default when the `#foo` no longer have class `open`

Comment: What's wrong with `$('#bar').css('position','fixed')` in the else branch? (IMHO you would always be better using classes to set styles, but this would work equally adding/removing classes).

Comment: Overall a better approach would be to make these changes when the controlling state (ie. that sets the `open` class on `#foo`) changes rather than using a timer. Perhaps if you clarified why you want to use a timer.

Comment: Once again I agree with @Richard. This code should be unnecessary, whatever adds the class `open` to `foo` should also add a class `foo-open` to `bar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need a timeout or interval for this. Take advantage of [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

```js
var open = 'someCondition';
if(open) {
    $('#foo').addClass('open');
    $('#bar').addClass('foo-open');
} else {
    $('#foo').removeClass('open');
    $('#bar').removeClass('foo-open');
}
```

```css
#bar {
    position: fixed;
}

#bar.foo-open {
    position: relative;
}
```

whatever code is responsible for adding the class `open` to `#foo` should also add a class `foo-open` to `#bar`.

Also have a look at [cssspecificity.com](http://cssspecificity.com/) for a fun visualization of CSS specificity.

Comment: aha... sound make sense and simpler than using jquery, I will try it and get back to you with the result

Comment: @YudyAnanda Also remember that if `#bar` is already inside `#foo` then this is all you would need: `.open #bar { position: relative; }` i.e. no need for the class `foo-open`. It all depends on your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`setInterval`** instead of **`setTimeout`**

```
function checkForChanges()
{
    if ($('#foo').hasClass('open'))
        $('#bar').css('position','relative');
    else
        $('#bar').css('position','fixed');
}  
setInterval(checkForChanges, 500);
```

Comment: Why `setInterval` why not `setTimeout` ?

Comment: @ShreeKhanal If you repeatedly use a timeout forever, that's what we call an interval. Every x milliseconds = interval. After x milliseconds = timeout.

Comment: @DJDaveMark Tanks for answer